# Python: use of eval in interactive terminal. how to get return value. what compile-mode

Tags: python, compilation, eval

I have some code like:

```
    try:
        c = compile(s, COMPILE_STRING_FN, "single")
    except Exception as e:
        answer = (idx, "compile-exception", (e.__class__.__name__, str(e)))
    else:
        try:
            ret = eval(c, globals, locals)
        except Exception as e:
            answer = (idx, "eval-exception", (e.__class__.__name__, str(e)))
        else:
            if ret is not None:
                try:
                    ret = str(ret)
                except Exception as e:
                    ret = "<str-cast exception: %s: %s>" % (e.__class__.__name__, str(e))
            answer = (idx, "return", ret)
```

This doesn't work as expected because `ret` is always `None` - the value, if there is any, will be printed instead. This is not what I want - I want to have it in `ret`.

It seems that `"single"` is not the correct compile-mode for me. Also, `s = "def f(): return 42"` does not work.

However, neither is `"eval"` because I want to support any commands, not just single expressions.

And with mode `"exec"`, I also would not get the return value.

So, what would be the solution?

---

An upstream suggestion: [compile-flag for single-execution to return value instead of printing it](http://bugs.python.org/issue17294)

---

Use case: Python remote shell. I have this implemented for [my application](https://github.com/albertz/music-player) to be able to attach it whenever I want. [server `socketcontrol` module](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/socketcontrol.py) and [client interactive shell implementation](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/socketcontrol-interactiveclient.py).

Comment: `def` to create a function is a statement, not an expression, so `eval` won't work on that.  You could use `lambda : 42` to `eval` something to a function object instead ...

Comment: Can you show some examples of the strings you are trying to evaluate?  If you don't mind my asking, what is this you are building?  It looks elaborate, and like there might be an easier way to do it, for example with the `code` module.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Anything that you can enter in the Python interactive terminal. I'm not getting `s` via stdin, so I think the `code` module is not an option.

Comment: @mgilson: `eval` should work in any case. It just depends on how the code is compiled. But that is actually the question itself.

Comment: @Albert: I'm not sure why you think the `code` module is limited to reading from stdin.  Spend a little more time understanding what it does, it could save you a lot of time.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: I'm not sure how it would help me. According to its doc, it does the same as I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `compile(s, COMPILE_STRING_FN, "single")`, I can use this function:

```
def interactive_py_compile(source, filename="<interactive>"):
    c = compile(source, filename, "single")

    # we expect this at the end:
    #   PRINT_EXPR     
    #   LOAD_CONST
    #   RETURN_VALUE    
    import dis
    if ord(c.co_code[-5]) != dis.opmap["PRINT_EXPR"]:
        return c
    assert ord(c.co_code[-4]) == dis.opmap["LOAD_CONST"]
    assert ord(c.co_code[-1]) == dis.opmap["RETURN_VALUE"]

    code = c.co_code[:-5]
    code += chr(dis.opmap["RETURN_VALUE"])

    CodeArgs = [
        "argcount", "nlocals", "stacksize", "flags", "code",
        "consts", "names", "varnames", "filename", "name",
        "firstlineno", "lnotab", "freevars", "cellvars"]
    c_dict = dict([(arg, getattr(c, "co_" + arg)) for arg in CodeArgs])
    c_dict["code"] = code

    import types
    c = types.CodeType(*[c_dict[arg] for arg in CodeArgs])
    return c
```